# Render TimePickerDialog on forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible for me to render the Android TimePickerDialog on a forms project? I've tried the TimePicker control on forms, but it's basically just a Textbox. which is not what i want. I want the TimePickerDialog as it displays in an Android project, but in a forms PCL.

Is this possible?

Would i have to use a custom renderer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The builtin time picker in Xamarin.Forms does not have an option to be rendered inline. To achieve that you will have to create a custom renderer and use [TimePicker widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) to show the picker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use a Forms' custom renderer to expose that dialog.

You would need a control that launched the `TimePickerDialog`, then when the user touches `Done`, you would grab the value and insert it back into your control.

The quickest way would be to subclass an `Entry` (or `Button`) control and launch the `TimePickerDialog` within the `OnElementChanged` event:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)

{
    base.OnElementChanged (e);

    if (Control != null) {
      ~~~~
    }
}
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/entry/

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the fast reply. But this is exactly where i get stuck when using a custom renderer. How do i show the disalog from here onwards?